# How to hide flash message after few seconds?

Tags: jquery, flash-message

In my application user can post challenge for other user. So after successful posting a challenge I am displaying one flash message for the same. But now I want to hide this message after some few seconds. So I wrote following code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#successMessage").hide('blind', {}, 500)
    }, 5000);
});

<div id="successMessage" style="text-align:center; width:100%">
    <FONT color="green">
        <%if flash[:alert]=="Your challenge is posted successfully."%> 
            <h4><%= flash[:alert] if flash[:alert].present? %>
        <%end%>
    </font>
</div>
```

But this code is not hiding the div "successMessage".

Comment: You need to call `setTimeout` after posting the message and not on `document.ready()`

Comment: @sweety I think that you need the [flash-message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash-message) instead of [flash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash) tag, I edited it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can try :

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#successMessage').fadeOut('fast');
}, 30000); // <-- time in milliseconds
```

If you used this then your div will be hide after 30 sec.I also tried this one and it worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [delay jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) to achieve this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#successMessage").delay(5000).slideUp(300);
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Someone posted a similar question to stackoverflow with this solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.setTimeout("document.getElementById('successMessage').style.display='none';", 2000); </script>

<div id="successMessage"> bla bla bla
</div>
```

I'd share the link but I can't find it anymore. Thanks for the help, though, mystery human!

Answer (score 1):

Some times it's not enough to only setting display of box to none it's better to completely remove it. as follows:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.alert-box').remove();
}, 30000);
```