# <script> placement in flask html pages

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, flask

I want to have my flash messages fading out using this code for that ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31176503/4225972)):

```
<script type="text/javascript">setTimeout(function() {$('#stepMessage').fadeOut('slow');}, 3000); </script>
```

my complete script looks like this:

**solution:**

in the base.html:
{% extends 'bootstrap/base.html' %}

```
{% block scripts %}
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.4.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script> <-- included JQuery
{% raw %}
<script type="text/javascript">window.setTimeout(function() {$('#stepMessage').fadeOut('slow');}, 3000); </script> <-- added function
{% endraw %}
{% endblock %}

{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import 'bootstrap/wtf.html' as wtf %}
```

in the index.html I was now able to use the function I previously defined:

```
{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
     .
     .
     .
    </div>


    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
    {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            {% set lvl = "alert-danger" if message[1]["result"] == False else "alert-info" %}
        <div id="stepMessage" class="alert {{ lvl }}" role="alert">{{  message[1]["content"] }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}

    {% block app_content %}
    {% endblock %}

{% endblock %}
```

Thanks to @Rishi Dev for the help

Comment: You should surround the Javascript code with {% raw %} and {% endraw %} tags so that the Javascript code is properly escaped.
https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#escaping

Comment: Thanks, I added that, but it did not change anything.

Comment: I suspect that you're using JQuery, but maybe you're forgetting to include it in the script ? Have you included the JQuery script also somewhere in your template ? If not, perhaps you should do that.

Comment: You need to include JQuery. Because the answer that you linked to, uses JQuery. You can include it by pasting this BEFORE your script tag 
`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.4.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: working now, thanks for the help. Code udpated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include JQuery.
Paste this tag before your script tag in the template

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.4.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```