# Self disappearing flash alerts (flask)

Tags: python, flask

I'm using `flash` alerts from `flask` to display success, warning or other bootstrap-class alerts in my flask app.
Is there a way to have these alerts nicely disappear with a fadeout after x seconds?
They all have `id="flash"`

Thank you!

Comment: This has been asked before, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31176402/how-to-hide-flash-message-after-few-seconds

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying this but I get a console error:

`TypeError: $(...).fadeOut is not a function`

Comment: @GuillermoBrachetta: if you're using a "slim" version of jQuery that will happen.

Comment: Ah yes!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: You're welcome! Happy coding to you.